# Find series expansion of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series, gaussian-integral

The question asks to find a series expansion of $\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{\frac{-s^2}{2}}ds$, given:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{s^n}e^{\frac{-s^2}{2}}ds=\frac{-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{x^{n+1}}-(n+1)\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{s^{n+2}}e^{\frac{-s^2}{2}}ds$$
I've come with with this series:
$$I(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^j \frac{1}{x^{2j+1}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \prod_{k=0}^{j} (2k+1)$$

but the ratio test shows that this series is divergent, which I think shouldn't be the case as the integral itself converges for all $x$.

edit: not a Taylor expansion! I'm required to come up with a series representation with the given recursive relation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of integrating by parts, use the Taylor series for $e^x$.  Replace the $x$ by $-x^2/2$ and integrate term by term.

Comment: What do you mean by "a series expansion"? Do you want a power series expansion at $x=0$ using [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)? Do you want a power series expansion in powers of $1/x$?

Comment: not a Taylor series, the question explicitly stated to use the given recursive relationship